# discord.js SQL command issue

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a rep command for my discord bot but im running into issues, This is the code i was using

```
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM rep WHERE UserID = '${member.id}'`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        if (!rows[0]) {
            $sql = sql = `INSERT INTO rep(UserID, rep) VALUES(${ member.id }, 0)`;
            connection.query(sql)
        } else {

        }
```

The issue was that it was not adding someone to the table, Basically It would add both the person that typed the command and the mentioned person into the table if they were not added in
At this point i keep messing up, Can someone lead me to a tutorial on making a rep command?

Comment: What's the intended functionality?

Comment: I doubt this would fix your issue but you should do `if (!rows)` instead of `if (!rows[0])`

Answer (score 0):

I saw problem, that some database systems are auto-converting string to int, when it is possible. But Node.JS can't hold int 64 (and ids are bigger than int 32). So try putting something as `id:` before the id, when you are storing it.

Answer (score 0):

I saw some problems with your code that typically are wrong but I don't know in your case because I don't know how you declared the member variable or its ID, si try this and tell me what's going on, maybe a little more bit of code would help or a console error. Thanks.

```
con.query(`SELECT * FROM rep WHERE UserID = '${member.user.id}'`, (err, rows) => {
if (err) {
  throw err;
}
if (rows.length < 1) {
   $sql = `INSERT INTO rep(UserID, rep) VALUES ('${member.user.id}', '1')`; // Because he got the $rep @mention command in the first place, he got 1 rep, not 0, I guess.
   connection.query(sql)
} else {

}
```

Comment: this is the member variable ```const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]) || message.member; ```

Comment: So my code is correct, you should use ${member.user.id} as a variable, and I guess you should delete "|| message.member;" from your constant.